# Is the itemrenderer function model inefficient or just the example?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4

I've heard or read somewhere that for performance reasons one should avoid the itemRendererFunction but being that I can't find the source of that comment is it possible that it's the example code in the docs that's inefficient instead? I've created an alternative code example that I think is much more efficient (haven't done tests).

Here is the example code from the docs. Notice that on each iteration a new class factory is created[1]:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import myComponents.MySimpleItemRendererFunction;
        import spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer;

        private function selectRenderer(item:Object):ClassFactory {
            var classFactory:ClassFactory;
            if (item is String) {
                // If the item is a String, use DefaultItemRenderer.
                classFactory = new ClassFactory(DefaultItemRenderer);
            }
            else {
                // If the item is an Object, use MySimpleItemRendererFunction.
                classFactory = new ClassFactory(MySimpleItemRendererFunction); 
            }
            return classFactory;
        }
    ]]>  
</fx:Script>
```

My code (not tested):

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        private var normalItemRendererFactory:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(DefaultItemRenderer);
        private var editableItemRendererFactory:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(EditableItemRenderer);

        private function itemRendererFunction(item:Object):ClassFactory {

            if (item is String) {
                // If the item is a String, use DefaultItemRenderer.
                return normalItemRendererFactory;
            }
            else {
                // If the item is an Object, use MySimpleItemRendererFunction.
                return editableItemRendererFactory;
            }
        }
    ]]>  
</fx:Script>
```

[1] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html#WS94F31173-40D5-4ddd-B7B3-17D02BD57EAF

Comment: Where is that code used in the docs?  Are you having performance issues you're trying to solve?  This question seems non-specific and I'm unclear if it can be discretely answerd.

Comment: Oops forgot to post the link. It's added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used an `itemRendererFunction` with the Flex 4.0 through 4.5 SDK's, the item renderers in your `List` are not recycled. This can have a big performance impact the scrolling performance of the list.

In Flex 4.6, they improved the functionality so that item renderers could be recycled when using an item renderer function.

You hit the nail on the head with the improvements you made to the example above. The first obvious improvement is that you're avoiding creating a new class factory each time. But there is something even more important, which will prevent the list from recycling renderers (even with Flex 4.6).

When the `itemRendererFunction` returns a new class factory each time, it messes up the list's internal tracking of item renderers, and causes the list to create new renderers rather than re-use them where possible. This then has the same performance impact on scrolling, and the added bonus of keeping the old renderers in memory.

This [particular problem is discussed here](http://www.frishy.com/2012/02/mis-using-itemrendererfunction-and-memory-leaks/).

Comment: Interesting: didn't even know about that issue. +1